# How to merge lines of CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv, merge

I have a CSV file that looks something like:

> Andrew Smith, andy@hotmail.co.uk, Manchester, UK 
>  Martin Jones,
>   martin@gmail.com, Reading, UK 
>   ***Shirley Andrews, , Los Angeles,*  
>
>   *Bob James, bobjames@yahoo.com, ,***  
>  Jacob Costelloe, jc@email.com, Sydney, Australia 
>   ***Shirley Andrews, shirley@mail.com, , US*** 
>  Callum Jones, callumjjones@btinternet.com, Paris, France 
>   ***Bob James, , London, UK***

Based on the first column (name), I need to merge the data, so returned from this I would get:

> Andrew Smith, andy@hotmail.co.uk, Manchester, UK 
>  Martin Jones,
>   martin@gmail.com, Reading, UK 
>   ***Bob James, bobjames@yahoo.com, London, UK***  
>  Jacob Costelloe, jc@email.com, Sydney, Australia 
>   ***Shirley Andrews, shirley@mail.com, Los Angeles, US*** 
>  Callum Jones, callumjjones@btinternet.com, Paris, France

Is there a simple way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Define "simple". If you mean a built-in function, the answer is no.

Comment: It's a bit much to expect PHP to know that L.A. is in the U.S. What if there was a 3rd Shirley Andrews, who happens to live in Tokyo?

Comment: Maybe you could open this up a bit. How is this data currently? Is it read line by line or is it already in arrays? You could make every row an array with explode(',', $row),  set key as the first variable and check out the user database if it is already set and the merge, otherwise add to user database. Finally export it in any way you want.

Comment: @MarcB It looks like the CSV has a field for City and a separate field for Country.  Note That "Los Angeles" appears in field 2 (0-indexed), but "US" appears in field 3.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this: http://codepad.org/MfYAycZk

As you can see, the output correlates the two Bob James together.

```
$text = "Andrew Smith, andy@hotmail.co.uk, Manchester, UK
Martin Jones, martin@gmail.com, Reading, UK
Shirley Andrews, , Los Angeles,
Bob James, bobjames@yahoo.com, ,
Jacob Costelloe, jc@email.com, Sydney, Australia
Shirley Andrews, shirley@mail.com, , US
Callum Jones, callumjjones@btinternet.com, Paris, France
Bob James, , London, UK";

$people = array();
foreach( explode( "\n", $text) as $line)
{
    $entries = explode( ',', $line);
    $entries = array_map( 'trim', $entries);
    list( $first_name, $last_name) = explode( ' ', $entries[0]);

    if( isset( $people[ $last_name ][ $first_name ])) {
        $people[ $last_name ][ $first_name ] = array_merge( $people[ $last_name ][ $first_name ], array( 
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email' => $entries[1],
            'city' => $entries[2],
            'country' => $entries[3]

        ));

    } else {

        $people[ $last_name ][ $first_name ] = array( 
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email' => $entries[1],
            'city' => $entries[2],
            'country' => $entries[3]
        );
    }
}

var_dump( $people);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `array_merge` will overwrite earlier values with empty strings, so my example is not complete.

Comment: What about `array_merge($existing, array_filter($new))`?

Answer (score 0):

This will format the text how you described:

```
$text = str_replace("\r", '', $text);

$container = explode("\n", $text);
$rows = array();

foreach ($container as $data) {
    $values = array_map('trim', explode(',', $data));

    $id = strtolower(trim($values[0]));

    if ($id) {                                
        if (true == isset($rows[$id])) {
            //remove blank
            $values = array_filter($values);

            foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
                if ($rows[ $id ][ $i ] == '') {
                   $rows[ $id ][ $i ] = $value;
                }
            }
       } else {
            $rows[ $id ] = $values;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: if your talking about if (true == isset($rows[$id])) { it could also be written as if (true === isset($rows[$id])) { since isset will return boolean

Comment: Why is the `true ==` part necessary?

Comment: because it means this name has already been processed once and were now just looking for the missing peices. If it isn't set we do not have any extra processing to do and add it as it is

Comment: Sorry; I meant, what is the difference between `if (true == isset(...))` and `if (isset(...))`?

Comment: there is very little difference both will work the same way, I find it easier to read